# ffmpeg: How to loop audio wave file into a video which has no any audio channel

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I loop audio wave or mp3 file into a video which has no any audio channel using ffmpeg?

that is my code already working for video files which has already audio channel.

```
ffmpeg -i somevideoinput.mp4 -stream_loop -1 
       -i will_be_looped.wav 
 -vcodec copy  
-max_muxing_queue_size 9999
-shortest
-fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 200M
-map 0:0 -map 1:0
 output.mp4
```

that replaces the video's auido channel with looped input wave file. but it does not work if video has no any audio channel already.

do you any idea? maybe some filter_complex parameters I gotto add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-stream_loop` is an input option, so it has to be used before `-i`:

```
ffmpeg -i somevideoinput.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i will_be_looped.wav 
-vcodec copy 
-max_muxing_queue_size 9999
-shortest
-fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 200M
-map 0:v -map 1:a
 output.mp4
```

I also changed the `-map` options to use stream specifiers to ensure that it selects the proper streams.

Comment: @KursatTurkay One book is [FFmpeg Basics](http://ffmpeg.tv/), but I am not familiar with the contents. *"still no audio if input movie has no already an audio channel"*. There should be audio because `-map` is selecting audio from `will_be_looped.wav`. To be able to understand the problem I will need to see your `ffmpeg` command and the complete log from the command. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63585078/edit) your question to include this info.

Comment: gr8 man <3 .you save my week. it was my console application if else bug not ffmpeg. if you wouldn't stand on your answer I could not detect my code bug. world really needs a pro ffmpeg book. searched everywhere still nothing exists yet we can say that book is really useful. I am working on ffmpeg for last 2 months. still it feels me so bad to understand ffmpeg syntax grammar.

Comment: @KursatTurkay Take a look at the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/#CommunityContributedDocumentation) to supplement the official [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html).